# Cherrypick revisions and rebuild repository

Tags: svn, automation

I have a svn repo that is getting uglier by the day.  I'd like to rebuild it, in an automated fashion that would be exactly the same as me manually performing the process as outlined below

1. Create a brand new empty repo
2. Export revision 109 to a local directory
3. Import revision 109 as first revision to new repo
4. Export revision *n* <--maybe I'll skip 20 revisions I don't care about
5. Commit the exported revision as rev2 to the new repo including that revs comments
6. Iterate through a specific list of revision numbers repeating steps 4-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import your repo into git and to it via `git rebase -i`.

Then, if necessary, push it back to a new svn repo. Or just forget about svn.

Comment: I'll never forget about svn.  Git seems to me the equivalent of using windows explorer as a vcs.

Comment: two years later, and I'm thinking of ditching svn. :P

Comment: @MVCylon He-he, never say never. Git rulez. Using git after svn feels like using Haskell after Visual Basic.